# Using P&T Select Dropdown field without updating to EE 2.6

Tags: pixelandtonic, field-pack

I need to use the Select Dropdown included in Pixel&Tonic's FieldPack, but I can't install FieldPack without updating EE to 2.6, which I can't do now. Is there an older version I could use? I searched P&T's website, but older versions don't seem to be available there. I don't need the whole FieldPack, really, only the select dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old Field Pack is still up on github: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/pt_field_pack

Comment: Got it, you answered like 2 minutes before P&T did, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give P&T a shout directly by email and I'm sure they've have an archived file for you.